# php socket timeout

Tags: php, sockets

i have a php server with an array of clients which are connected to the server..
is there a way for me to find out for how long each client is connected and if the client passed the timeout time to disconnect it ? does php save somewhere the time the socket were accepted ?
i'm trying to get rid of ghost clients..

i know that i can set the time the socket accepted myself and to loop throw it but my question if there is some kind of socket_get_connection_time() function of something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is using signals, if you are using a Unix-based platform (I don't believe this is available on Windows).

First, you need to make sure your PHP build includes the pcntl_* functions. See docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php  On many installations, it is not compiled in by default.

You would do something like this:

```
if( !function_exists( "pcntl_signal" ) ) {
    die("pcntl_* functions not available");
}

pcntl_signal( 14, "cleanup", TRUE ); // 14 is the value for the SIGALARM unix signal
pcntl_alarm( XXXX ); // where XXXX is the number of second timeout for doing maintenance

function cleanup()
{
   // do your checks for timed out sockets here.
   // you will need some way to access the data, possibly a global variable pointing to
   // to the list of socket connections.
}
```